# image not getting displayed dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am hidding one image in my html page using hidden property. but i am not able to make it visible through java script by `document.getElementById("check").style.visibility="visible";`
my code is

```
   <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style><script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("check").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table> 
<img class="hide" src="check.jpg" id="check" hidden="true" height="300" width="400">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="1.jpeg" onclick="myFunction()">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting `hidden="true"` to hide it, then you will need to unset this property to display the element again.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
</style><script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("check").hidden = '';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table> 
<img class="hide" src="check.jpg" id="check" hidden="true" height="300" width="400">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="1.jpeg" onclick="myFunction()">
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You actually forget to assign something to that variable in your function

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("check").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

You also have to remove hidden attribute and to delete your "hide" class

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
    return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}
function removeClass(ele,cls) {
    if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
    var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
    ele.className = ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
}
function myFunction() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("check");
    ele.style.visibility = "visible";
    ele.hidden = "";
    removeClass(ele, "hide");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change and apply the `visibility` CSS.

```
function myFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("check").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

It is better to set the visibility on load using script.

```
document.getElementById("check").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

As sometimes, when you define in CSS, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>      
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction()
        {
            document.getElementById("check").style.visibility="visible";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table> 
        <img  src="check.jpg" id="check" hidden="true" height="300" width="400" style="visibility:hidden;"/>    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="1.jpeg" onclick="myFunction()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```